# Why I can't use req.body as parameter directly?

Tags: node.js, express, post, push, req

I am learning [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js).

Here is the code.  It works well.

However, I don't understand why I can't use req.body as a parameter directly?

```
articlesInfo[articleName].comments.push({req.body.username,req.body.text});
```

Thanks.

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';

const articlesInfo ={
  'learn-react':{
    upvotes:0,
    comments:[],
  },
  'learn-node':{
    upvotes:0,
    comments:[],
  },
  'learn-js':{
    upvotes:0,
    comments:[],
  },
}

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/api/articles/:name/add-comment',(req,res)=>{
  const {username,text} = req.body;
  const articleName = req.params.name;
  articlesInfo[articleName].comments.push({username,text});
  res.status(200).send(articlesInfo[articleName]);
});

app.listen(8000,()=>console.log("Listening on port 8000"));
```

Comment: Because `{req.body.username,req.body.text}` is invalid syntax. `{username: req.body.username, text: req.body.text}` would be valid… So probably, `.push(req.body)` would do…

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I got it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason why you can't use :

```
articlesInfo[articleName].comments.push({req.body.username,req.body.text});
```

is because it's a syntax error, you're creating an object without any keys, you're only setting the values.

```
articlesInfo[articleName].comments.push({username: req.body.username, text: req.body.text});
```

Here you now have key/value pairs.

The reason why the other one is working is because because of [ES2015 shorthand properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understand now.